# Stuck on Problem 21 of Chapter 3.4 in Velleman's How to prove it

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am stuck on problem 21 of chapter 3.4 in Velleman's How to Prove it.
Here is what has to be proven.
$F$ and $G$ are Families of Sets. So $\cup F$ is the union of the sets contained in $F$.
$$\cup F\setminus\cup G\subseteq\cup(F\setminus G)$$
And here is what I have got:
Suppose $x\in(\cup F\setminus\cup G)$.
This implies that $\exists A\in F (x\in A)$ and $\forall B\in G(x\notin B)$
To show that $\cup F\setminus\cup G\subseteq\cup(F\setminus G)$
We need to show that $x\in \cup(F\setminus G)$
This means $\exists C \in (F\setminus G)(x\in C)$
This amounts to saying that $\exists C (C\in F \land C\notin G \land x\in C)$
If we choose $C=A$ then clearly $C\in F$ and $x\in C$.
But I still have to show that $C\notin G$.
I did something wrong here.
Is it perhaps better to shows this via the contrapositive method?

Comment: Can you please give some context for this exercise? The notation “$\cup F$” isn't clear. What are $F$ and $G$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Sorry about that. I will edit the question.

Comment: Assuming that "/" is $\setminus$ "(setminus) we have to consider what is the "difefrence" of the two families $F$ and $G$: it is famili - call it $D$ - such that $D = \{ C \mid C \in F \text { and } C \notin G \}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, isn't that what I tried to do?

Comment: Thus, your $x$ above belongs to an $A \in F$ but belongs to no $B \in G$. This means that $A$ cannot be in $G$ and so $A$ is in $D$.

Comment: Yes of course! That was the final nail in the coffin! Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by $X/Y$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila by that i mean the set difference. Sorry about the sloppy notation. I didn't know how to do the \ in LaTex.

Comment: `\setminus`, now, there's an [edit] function for a reason...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the proof outlined in the question. Just one more step was required as Mauro ALLEGRANZA pointed out:
Since $x$ belongs to an $A\in F$ and $x$ does not belong to any $B\in G$ $A$ cannot be an element in $G$.
Therefore all the conjuncts in the statement to be proven are satisfied if we choose $C=A$ and the theorem is proven.

Comment: @ryang totally forgot about it. It takes usually 2 days till one can accept ones own answer. =) thanks for reminding me.